# Difference between list and [] in F#

Tags: collections, types, f#, f#-interactive

I am porting some Haskell code to F# but a bit confused about the collections available and their signatures in F#. My understanding is that elements in lists are enclosed between [ ], sequences between { }, and arrays between [| |]. In F# Interactive, I get the following when I create each container with 5 ints.

```
// List
> [1..5]
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]

// Seq
> {1..5}
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...]

// Array
> [|1..5|]
val it : int [] = [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5|]
```

What confuses me is that the type signature for arrays is `int []`. May be type `int array` or `int [||]` would be less confusing? Looking at the type signature, I tend to think it is a list, especially because an empty list is also represented as [].

One question here: why is sequence type `seq<int>` and not `int seq`. I am assuming this may be syntactic sugar but may be there is something else behind this.

Now creating new types using the collection:

```
type T1 = T1 of int list
type T2 = T2 of int seq // becomes type T2 = T2 of seq<int>
type T3 = T3 of int array
type T4 = T4 of int []
```

Is T3 and T4 the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# allows you to use .Net style type definitions and ocaml style type definitions.  These are the same.

```
int list
list<int>  

int seq
seq<int>

int array
array<int>
```

Some [Expressions in F#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597435) are

```
[||] is an array
[] is a list
```

In a type definition you can also do `int []`.  Which is C like syntax sugar.  Yep, T3 and T4 are the same.

You can't however do this `[]<int>`.  `[]` is a bit strange since it behaves as the type array in a type definition and as op_Nil in an expression.

Comment: Some Trivia: The type int[][,] in F# is the same as the type int[,][] in C# although the dimensions are swapped. This is for consistency with other postfix type names in F# such as int list list.

Comment: You might also find this interesting.  http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2009/01/29/f-and-haskell-estranged-cousins.aspx